# ¿Un moderador ♦ suspendido debería poder seguir moderando?

Tags: bug, moderación, moderadores

Soy moderador ♦ del sitio, y he autosuspendido mi cuenta (por tambalear en las elecciones), y veo que todavía puedo seguir moderando y algunas cosas más.

Ejemplos de cosas que no puedo hacer:

> - Votar en las publicaciones (preguntas y respuestas).
> - Editar comentarios.
> - Editar publicaciones.
> - Eliminar publicaciones.
> - Publicar preguntas ni en Meta ni en el sitio principal.

Ejemplos de cosas que puedo hacer:

> - Convertir respuestas en comentarios.
> - Entrar en los chats a pesar de no tener la reputación suficiente (los usuarios suspendidos tienen 1 punto).
> - Suspender usuarios.
> - Quitar mi suspensión (y de hecho lo hice para poder publicar esto).

En fin, quiero decir, un moderador suspendido todavía puede moderar en algunos aspectos. ¿Esto tiene que ser así o es un bug?

Comment: No creo que esté contemplado el caso de uso de moderadores de la comunidad autosuspendidos... supongo que es la primera vez que algo así sucede en los casi 10 años que tiene la red.

Comment: Sinceramente, me sorprende tu actitud. Parece como si ser moderador para ti fuese tu plataforma de juegos/pruebas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ No, es que me sentí un poco presionado con los últimos comentarios que habían en mi cuestionario, ya no tenía escapatoria... Deseo seguir ayudando en el sitio en lo que me resta por ser moderador, que son unos pocos días.

Comment: ¿Consideras que banearte a ti mismo ayuda al sitio?

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Realmente no, solo quería liberar un poco mis nervios.

Comment: ¿Crees que es positivo eso como imagen de moderador? ¿Consideras que realmente esto fue lo mejor? Sabes que siempre puedes contactarme en el chat y te apoyaré en lo que sea. En fin, pienso que aprendas mucho de esta lección. En lo personal, me siento impresionado (y no puedo negar que un poco decepcionado).

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ No es positivo, tampoco fue lo mejor ni mucho menos. Lamento haber tomado esta alternativa, fue la única que se me ocurrió.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque este pibe esta quemado XD.

Comment: @EmanuelVe pensé que tu comentario era jocoso, pero veo que de verdad planeas cerrarla por ese motivo... la pregunta tiene fundamento aunque sea descubierto a raiz de "estar quemado" como dices

Comment: Recuerda lo que comentamos : "Un gran poder conlleva a una gran responsabilidad", trata de pensar antes de tomar decisiones, como moderador realizando este tipo de acciones, podrías ocasionar problemas incluso al sitio o a usuarios. @ArtEze

Comment: @lois6b era jocoso.

Comment: @EmanuelVe me refiero a que no solo es un comentario, es un voto de cierre. Pensé que era comentario con *apariencia* de voto de cierre...

Comment: @lois6b si, ya retire el voto. ese que queda no es mio.

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿Cuales?

Comment: @Rubén no creo que sea muy práctico ir relanzando temas por una simple adición de etiquetas, pues creo que confunden a la gente y pueden parecer temas nuevos. Sugiero hacer tan útil reetiquetación cuando haya algo con más empaque a mejorar/editar, un poco como se hace con el código fuente en los programas (cuando añades funcionalidades, aprovechas para mejorar lo antiguo). Es una idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depende.

Lo que has hecho no es ninguna novedad. Ya ha habido moderadores que han experimentado con el sistema para comprender mejor como funciona: [Is it possible for a moderator to be auto-banned from reviewing in the queues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284136/956880)
En esa respuesta mencionan que banear a un moderador tiene poca relevancia puesto que puede desbanearse a si mismo. Lo cual significa que es una situación que conocen, no es algo imprevisto. Que un moderador baneado pueda seguir moderando no es un bug, forma parte del funcionamiento normal del sitio. Para suspender a un moderador se usan otros procedimientos.

También recuerdo el caso de un moderador llamado Will [que por error publicó información privada de otros usuarios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187557/348498). Algo muy grave. Pero ni le banearon ni le suspendieron como moderador. Todo el mundo puede equivocarse y no se va a suspender a un moderador por cometer un error. Sirva esto para tranquilizar a futuros moderadores, si por error suspendéis a alguien tampoco es el fin del mundo, tiene remedio.

Desde luego, si hubieses hecho esto con otro moderador como Mendoza o FredyFx entonces sí merecerías ser suspendido como moderador. Sería un claro abuso de poder. Ni siquiera como experimento sería aceptable.
Pero esta y otras acciones similares sobre ti mismo no perjudican a nadie.

No dejes de buscar trabajo en el mundo del Control de Calidad en software, está claro que tienes un talento natural para el tema.

Comment: Gracias por la información y consejos, la pregunta iba hacia otro lado, pero esto me despejó varias dudas.

Comment: @ArtEze No es un bug. He editado la respuesta para que quede más explícito.