# ¿Es correcto votar las publicaciones de mi usuario borrado?

Tags: discusión, votos

¿Qué puedo decir? Las preguntas que hice anteriormente, algunas me gustan y parecen buenas respuestas, y otras no tanto.

¿Es correcto votarlas las preguntas de mi antiguo usuario eliminado con el usuario nuevo?

¿y a las del Sockpuppet eliminado? Que tampoco me parecen malas respuestas.

Dejo el planteo para el que quiera debatirlo.

---

Quiero dejar de lado el hecho de que la pregunta la hice yo en el pasado, simplemente vi la pregunta y me pareció buena.

Ya que como yo era activo, no era muy complicado encontrar una pregunta mía por casualidad y votarla.

¿Es necesario estar constantemente filtrando en mi pensamiento, esta no la voto porque fue mía? Para el sistema, esa persona no soy yo, o en realidad, sí, si algún día se usaran los backups del sitio y todo volviera a la normalidad (muy improbable).

Si estuviera fuera prohibido al menos habría un cartel diciendo: "Esta pregunta la realizó tu antigua cuenta, no puedes votarla"

También quiero dejar de lado la autoevaluación, simplemente estoy evaluando una pregunta, no digo que la voto pensando que fue mía, solo la estoy votando.

Comment: recomendaria una pregunta por post

Comment: Si deseas debatirlo lo preferible seria el chat.

Comment: En mi opinion estarías practicando el [Sock Puppeting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuenta_de_usuario_t%C3%ADtere) al hacer eso. Lo cual no me parece correcto. Mi recomendación es que no te votes a ti mismo bajo ninguna circunstancia. Se que no tienes malas intenciones, pero de igual modo.

Comment: @DanteS. no estoy seguro de que encaje por que se refiere a una cuenta borrada y no a dos cuentas activas. tampoco recibiría beneficio de hacerlo ...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Es un caso diferente. Esa pregunta explica por qué borrarían la cuenta, pero en este caso, se plantea lo que se hace luego de borrarla.

Comment: Porque eliminaste tu usuario viejo, si yo recuerdo que tenias buena cantidad de ptos?

Comment: @ArtEze lo que agregaste a la publicación cambia el contexto de una discusión una solicitud por eso he revertido la edición que has realizado, saludos.

Comment: @Japv Fue solo curiosidad por ver qué pasaba.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Ah, no, no estoy pidiendo que se agregue el cartelito, pero tampoco lo veo mala idea, de momento veo que no está prohibido.

Comment: @ArtEze y que pasó, que descubriste

Comment: @Japv Me llegó el correo, y vi que podía crear nuevamente la cuenta, eso no sabía, y al crearla sigue vinculado con el chat, de esa manera se gana la medalla de los 10 favoritos.

Comment: La edición que hicieron a esta pregunta invalida mi respuesta... cual es la gracia ???

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Tu respuesta está bien, al ver tu respuesta, pensé que no me di a explicar del todo bien, y decidí editarla para estar más acorde a lo que pienso. El tema es que cuando alguien ve una respuesta correcta piensan, como ya está resuelta no la respondo, pienso que fue este el caso... Sugiero que vuelvas a dejar la respuesta como estaba, y si se te ocurre algo más para agregar, mejor.

Comment: asi no funciona el sitio en meta... tu expones una duda y se vota y se responde ... pero si cada 5 dias la editas y cambias el contexto no hay respuesta que valga

Comment: @ArtEze lo primero que te dije fue que hicieras un POST por Pregunta o Contexto ..

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Es que le faltaba esa parte a mi pregunta, pensé que se entendía inicialmente. Para mí, sí, vale tu respuesta. Como bien dijiste, No hay problema en emitir votos... En definitiva, la respuesta está correcta.

Comment: Esta eliminación de usuario fue algo poco... práctico, ArtEze. Entiendo que te guste hacer pruebas, pero mirando la documentación ya podrías haber tenido una visión bastante clara de lo que iba a pasar. Me recuerda cuando hiciste lo de [¿Un moderador ♦ suspendido debería poder seguir moderando?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2558/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' La documentación algunas veces no lo soluciona todo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Respuesta invalidada con la edición que aceptaron los moderadores en el POST de pregunta, no hubiera dado ninguna respuesta ya que ahora se esta solicitando un banner y la pregunta ha cambiado a ser un post con múltiples preguntas y dudas...

<del>La auto evaluación es buena; pero el hecho de emitir votos a un usuario en especifico, sea uno tuyo borrado o de otra persona va en contra de los objetivos del sitio; incluso si haces votos en serie, el bot de la comunidad los va a reversar.</del>

<del>La respuesta es la siguiente; no hay problema con que emita votos... pero éticamente yo opino que no es correcto, ***te hago la siguiente pregunta:***</del>

<del>***Emitirías votos negativos a las malas preguntas de tu usuario?***</del>

<del>Parte de la Objetividad de los voto es ser imparcial, emitir votos, no debe estar relacionado a que cuenta o de quien es la cuenta ... debe estar relacionado a el POST (Preguntas y Respuesta) en donde se evalúa su contenido y calidad para que sea útil a la comunidad.</del>

Comment: Muy buena respuesta

Comment: La respuesta está bien, de todos modos la dejaré como correcta para que no salte el bump del usuario Comunidad, que no me gusta mucho que ande relanzando preguntas eternamente.